# Onclick attribute for button create inside Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm stuck in a problem.
The onclick property for the button created inside Javascript is not working
Here is my code:

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLoGc.png)

Reply function:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTBge.png)

Comment: Post code not images.

Comment: Define "is not working". What steps have you taken to debug this code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, btw. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.className = 'btn btn-outlline-primary';
button.value = 'Reply';
button.setAttribute("onclick", "YOURFUNCTIONNAME()");
div.appendChild(button);
```

you can give your button an onclick funtion with `setAttribute`